# Flex socket and erlang socket communication problem

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, http, sockets, erlang

I'm creating a client-server game. My client is a flex based game, and my server is erlang server.
At the beginning, when I test directly my flex client in flash player, I can establish a connection easily to my erlang server through socket connection. And both can exchange data with no problem.

The problem rise when I deploy my flex app at Apache http server, and running it using a browser by calling http://localhost/ ... my flex socket sends message requesting for a crossdomain policy to my erlang server.

So I create an xml message that represent a crossdomain policy, and send it back to my flex app as a response for that request.

Yet still I can't establish any permanent socket connection between my flex client and my erlang server. I know this because I add listener on my flex socket that will modify its internal state to CONNECTED, if a connection between client-server has established.

Comment: First, why are you using Flex for a game?  Seems like overkill to include a UI framework library for a game that probably has very little UI (I'm assuming here...).  Second, why are you using your own custom socket instead of using something that's widely available (AMF over long-polling (BlazeDS, GraniteDS) or RTMP (LCDS)) or use a commercially available server like Wowza or SmartFoxServer.  Seems like a lot of work to just create your own socket.

Comment: If you asks why am I creating my own game server ... the answer is not commercial .. but more to emotional :) ...

Comment: Okay, fine, then why are you using Flex?

Comment: Having the Flex SDK, it's possible to develop Flash-only SWF files. Perhaps the OP does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't experienced the problem but maybe this would help.

> The default policy file is named
>   crossdomain.xml and resides at the
>   root directory of the server that is
>   serving the data...
>   You can use the loadPolicyFile() method to access a nondefault policy file.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=deployingoverview_12.html

> A policy file served by an XMLSocket
>   server has the same syntax as any
>   other policy file, except that it must
>   also specify the ports to which access
>   is granted. When a policy file comes
>   from a port lower than 1024, it can
>   grant access to any ports; when a
>   policy file comes from port 1024 or
>   higher, it can grant access only to
>   other ports 1024 and higher.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00005403.html

Comment: After reading some explanations on flash domain policy things ... I found out how exactly flash player process cross domain connection ... and I found this link: https://github.com/saulabs/flashpolicy-erlang ... this link taught me how erlang socket server manage cross domain policy request ... maybe I'll try to implement what's the github project has shown me first ... thanks for all the advices, I'll soon checks all those links you gave me ...

Comment: Ok, this is what I did and success:

1) Based on the project I found in github (github.com/saulabs/flashpolicy-erlang), and information on how policy file works (http://www.senocular.com/pub/adobe/crossdomain/policyfiles.html), I modified my server... to listen for policy file request and return the loaded policy file as a response then close the connection.
2) After my flex client received a policy file it will try to reconnect, and when a new connection established, the flash Event.CONNECT will throwed and now everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

The flashplayer restricts your socket usage in several ways. One you already found out :) The other is to specify whether you use the network or not. There is a networking mode and a file system mode (access to the filesystem). You can't have both.

So you should try to compile it with this:

```
-use-network=true
```

---

And yes I know it's a PITA doing socket programming with flash. You should implement every OnErrorXYZ method and print as much information as possible. Using wireshark or a different network sniffer is also a good idea.